# Javascript/jQuery Regular Expression code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working with jqDock on a DotNetNuke project.  I ran jQuery.noConflict() and went through the jqDock.js file and changed all '$' to 'jQuery' (though I don't think it was necessary).
In this little bit of code I have an issue:

```
altImage : function(){
      var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
      return (alt && alt.match(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i)) ? alt : false;

    } //end function altImage()
```

At the end of the regular expression there is a chunk that says `$/i`, My find/replace set this to jQuery.  It broke the program.  Is this because that '$' symbol isn't associated with jQuery there?  Is it part of the Regular Expression?  If so...what exactly is it saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual style to writing jQuery plugins would mean that one would not need to replace `$` throughout the plugin. *Most* plugins are written such that the plugin code is surrounde by a self-invoking anonymous function that passes in `jQuery` for a parameter `$` such that `$` refers to the jQuery object inside of that function. Like so

```
(function($) {

    // I can happily use $ here to refer to the jQuery object
    $.fn.myFunction ....

})(jQuery);
```

So be careful when doing a naive find/replace.

As others have already mentioned, in the context of a regular expression, `$` is used to match the end of the string.

Finally, when using `$.noConflict()`, you can assign the `jQuery` object to a different alias and use that alias throughout the subsequent code. For example

```
var $j = $.noConflict();

// can use $j alias for jquery now
$j(document).ready(function($) { 
    // can use $j or $ for jQuery object inside this function as the 
    // jQuery object is passed in 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$` sign in this case is used as part of the regular expression, not as a call to jQuery, so that's why you had problems.  It matches the end of the string that the regular expression is being performed on.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` matches the end of the string so it's not jQuery related here.

Some reading on regexp can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX)

Answer (score 1):

Be **really careful** when doing such huge find/replaces in your code. You changed the `$` sign used in a regular expression to a jQuery expression, which is wrong. Every `replace` of this magnitude (replace everything in a document by other string) should be done wisely.

Read [noConflict documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) to see which options do you have when using it - there's even one that let's you still use `$` for jQuery.